# How to change the fill of p5js 3d Geometries

Tags: javascript, p5.js

These are the geometries:
http://p5js.org/examples/examples/3D_Geometries.php

I've already tried the syntax for the 2d shapes but it doesn't appear to work. Is there a special syntax for the WEBGL shapes, or can the color simply not be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ambientMaterial(color);`, you have to use that with lights to se a result.

See this page for explanation: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Getting-started-with-WebGL-in-p5#lights-and-materials